# Catching and responding to the Connman 'RequestInput' method call with QtDBus

Tags: qt, dbus, connman

I'm building a simple Qt-based application for monitoring and connecting to WiFi networks. I'm interfacing with Connman via its D-Bus APIs, and am able to scan for available networks, turn on/off technologies and register an agent as expected. I'm currently unable to provide the requested passphrase when the Connman RequestInput method is called (when attempting to connect to a protected/secure network), as I'm unsure how to bind the RequestInput method with a function in Qt.

Below is some indicative code which outlines the approach:

```
//Create a QDBusConnection systemBus() object
QDBusConnection connection = QDBusConnection::systemBus();

//Ensure the systemBus() connection is established
if (!connection.isConnected()) {
    qDebug() << "Connection error.";
}

//Create a Connman Manager D-Bus API interface object
QDBusInterface manager("net.connman", "/", "net.connman.Manager", connection);

//Register an agent with the Connman Manager API
manager.call("RegisterAgent", QVariant::fromValue(QDBusObjectPath("/test/agent")));

//Attempt to bind the mySlot() function with the net.connman.Agent RequestInput method
//This does not currently work
connection.connect("",
                   "/test/agent",
                   "net.connman.Agent",
                   "RequestInput",
                    this,
                    SLOT(mySlot(QDBusObjectPath, QVariantMap)));

//Create a Connman Service D-Bus API interface object (for a specific WiFi Service)
QDBusInterface service("net.connman",
                       "/net/connman/service/[WIFI SERVICE]",
                       "net.connman.Service",
                        connection);

//Attempt to connect to the secure WiFi network
//Note: this network has not previously been connected, so the RequestInput method is guaranteed to be called
service.call("Connect");

QVariantMap myClass::mySlot(const QDBusObjectPath &path, const QVariantMap &map)
{
    //Connman Agent RequestInput() method received
}
```

As commented above, the attempted binding of the /test/agent path, net.connman.Agent interface and RequestInput method to the mySlot() function does not work; there are no errors reported but the mySlot() function is never called. If I enable debugging with the QDBUS_DEBUG environment variable, I receive the following:

```
QDBusConnectionPrivate(0xffff74003a00) got message (signal): QDBusMessage(type=MethodCall, service=":1.3", path="/test/agent", interface="net.connman.Agent", member="RequestInput", signature="oa{sv}", contents=([ObjectPath: /net/connman/service/[WIFI SERVICE]], [Argument: a{sv} {"Passphrase" = [Variant: [Argument: a{sv} {"Type" = [Variant(QString): "psk"], "Requirement" = [Variant(QString): "mandatory"]}]]}]) )
```

The above is exactly what I'd expect; the RequestInput method is being called for the /test/agent path on the net.connman.Agent interface with the oa{sv} signature.

My questions:

1. How do I 'connect' to the RequestInput method call, such that my mySlot() function can parse the RequestInput method data?
2. How do I return the required QVariantMap from within mySlot()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the debug output it appears that ConnMan is doing a `MethodCall`, but `QDBusConnection::connect()` is for handling DBus singals, which is why your slot is not invoked.

You need to register an object implementing the `net.connman.Agent` interface onto the corresponding path, so that ConnMan can invoke your methods:

```cpp
class ConnManAgent : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_CLASSINFO("D-Bus Interface", "net.connman.Agent")
public:
    ConnManAgent(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    Q_INVOKABLE QVariantMap RequestInput(const QDBusObjectPath &, const QVariantMap &);

   // ... Rest of the net.connman.Agent interface
};
```

and then register it on the respective path:

```cpp
connection.registerObject(
    QStringLiteral("/test/agent"),
    new ConnManAgent(this), 
    QDBusConnection::ExportAllInvokables);
```

This exports all methods marked with `Q_INVOKABLE` to DBus. You might also mark them as `Q_SLOTS` and use `ExportAllSlots`, that's mostly up to you.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly the information I needed to fully understand managing D-Bus methods.